# onblur used for validation skips to next field

Tags: javascript, validation

part of the form shown below:

```js
function validatenumber(Num)
{
  var x=Num.value;
  if (isNaN(parseFloat(x)) && isFinite(x) == false)
    {
      Num.value="";
      alert("Not a valid number");
      Num.focus();
    }
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="qty1">Full Series: $135.00</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input name="qty1" type="text" id="qty1" size="5" onblur="validatenumber(this)"/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="qty2">Mini-Series: $115.00</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input name="qty2" type="text" id="qty2" size="5" onblur="validatenumber(this)"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

if a non-number is entered in first field (qty1), the error alert pops up as expected, the field (qty1) is cleared but the focus moves to the next field (qty2) rather than staying in qty1. Also, if a non-number is entered into qty2 field no alert is given.

Not expected behavior. Solutions?

thanks

have no idea what to change. That's why I'm asking

Comment: In the provided code snippet, 1) the focus does not move to the second field when the first one is invalid, and 2) when a non-number is entered into the second field, an alert does pop up.  Can you clarify the problem or provide a better reproduction?

Comment: You could simply add the input to only accept number or use this sort of thing. <input id ="qty1" size="5" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' /> It is not ideal as depending of the form but you have provided limited code, you will need Javascipt. In your html set the id or name to 1,2,34 to the input and get the javascript to select the the next input providing previous is entered as you want i.

Comment: benbotto - run the code snippet. it works as described.

Comment: @user2970733 if you meant that after the entered line, place the cursor on the next field, then see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was possible to stay on focus only using `setTimeout`.
Without it it only worked in chrome. I also read that alert() removes focus. And indeed in opera using setTimeout the focus was not saved. Instead of `alert()`, I used `<style>` to color the input field and write "enter number" in it.

[Here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53579) is information on the topic.

```js
function validatenumber(Num)
{
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("focusout", function() {
    if(isNaN(event.target.value) && 
         isFinite(event.target.value) == false)
       {
         event.target.value = "";
         var ev = event.target.id;
         setTimeout(function() {
         document.getElementById(ev).classList.add("error");
         document.getElementById(ev).value = "enter number";
         document.getElementById(ev).focus();
         }, 1);
        } 
       else {
      this.classList.remove("error");
    }    

    });
});
}
```

```html
<body>

<style>
  .error {
    background: red;
  }
</style>

<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="qty1">Full Series: $135.00</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input name="qty1" type="text" id="1" size="10" 

onblur="validatenumber(this)"/>
  </td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="qty2">Mini-Series: $115.00</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input name="qty2" type="text" id="2" size="10" 

onblur="validatenumber(this)"/>
  </td>
</tr>

<script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: the snippet was just that, a snippet. the actual form has many more fields. and if the value is not a number it is supposed to clear it and stay in that field not move on to the next one

Comment: At first I understood that you want to jump to another field if the input is incorrect. Then your code works for me: I enter a line on the left, an alert comes out, the cursor remains on the same field. Input number remains and the cursor on the same field. Also with the field on the right. I changed the code so that the focus is on the current input. 

And I added an variant where when a number is entered and the cursor moves out of the field, the cursor moves to the next field.